# Geom_ribbon manipulation

Tags: r

I want Reorder the statements that created my graph so that the ribbon is on the bottom and the data points are on top and the regression line is visible. I used the code below but it does not give me the desired representation. Below is the data frame and code:

```
Rosy <- data.frame(
      times = c(15, 11, 9, 12, 5, 2, 3),
      day   = 1:7,
      yhat  = c(14.36, 12.29, 10.21, 8.14, 6.07, 4.00,  1.93),
      lwr   = c( 9.54,  8.5,   7.22, 5.47, 3.08, 0.22, -2.89),
      upr   = c(19.18, 16.07, 13.2, 10.82, 9.06, 7.78,  6.75))

ggplot(data = Rosy, aes(x=day)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=times)) +
  geom_line( aes(y=yhat)) +
  geom_ribbon( aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), fill='salmon')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of your elements:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = Rosy, aes(x=day)) +
  geom_ribbon( aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), fill='salmon')+
  geom_point(aes(y=times)) +
  geom_line( aes(y=yhat))
```

[image]

You know you could also use `geom_smooth`:

```
ggplot(data = Rosy, aes(x=day, y=times)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", fill = "salmon", color="black")+
 # geom_ribbon( aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), fill='salmon')+
  geom_point(aes(y=times))
```

[image]

Comment: but the regression line is not visible